# What logic can I use to allow x number of values in a table column?

Tags: php, mysql

We are trying to make a mod on a football pool website, that has the feature to use one joker per user. We want to be able to have more than one joker.

This piece of code below checks if a user didn't already store 1 joker.

```
// only allow setting of joker if it wasn't used before on a played match 
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT m.play_date 
                            FROM {$prefix}predictions p, {$prefix}matches m  
                            WHERE p.match_id = m.id AND p.has_joker = 1 AND p.user_id = %d"  
                            , $user 
                        ); 
    $play_date = $wpdb->get_var( $sql ); 
    if ( $play_date ) { 
        $play_date = new DateTime( $play_date ); 
        $ts = $play_date->format( 'U' ); 
        if ( $matches->match_is_editable( $ts ) ) { 
            $joker = $this->get_joker(); 
        } 
    } else { 
        $joker = $this->get_joker(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch query results even though you never actually run the query.  Between `$wpdb->prepare` and `$wpdb->get_var` lines, you need to:

1. execute the query (you only prepared it)
2. check for error (did it execute successfully)
3. check whether it returned any record

Only then can you start using the query results

Comment: there is more code to that. I am just asking for help on how to check for the joker and after  they use one of them, increment and update has_joker.